# Has_many through a has_many in Rails 3.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

I have a User model that allows users to follow other users.  Each User also has many Things:

```
class User
  has_many :following, :class_name => 'Followings', :foreign_key => 'follower_id'
  has_many :things
end
```

What I would ultimately like to do is get all the things from all the users that a user is following and be able to paginate this query.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want the data separated out.  This will give you a unique array of all the things, without keeping which of the followed users they belong to:

```
@user = User.first
@things = @user.followings.map(&:things).flatten.uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is for:

```
class User
  # ...
  has_many :followed_users, :through => :followings, :source => :followed
  has_many :followed_things, :through => :followed_users, :source => :things
end
```

The `:source` option is described in the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).